# How to locate the webelement 'User Role' under admin menu in opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com using Selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath, drop-down-menu, webdriver

I find difficult in finding the locator for the webelement 'User Role' within the website: https://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/web/index.php/admin/saveSystemUser

Steps:

1. login to the above siteusing user id:admin,pwd:admin123
2. click on 'Admin' >'User Management'
3. click on 'Add user"
4. I want to choose 'ESS' from 'User Role' drop down
   But im not able to find the locator for ESS webelement.
   Pls help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem:** The dropdown values are disappearing elements, which means you cannot inspect the elements and locate the desired element easily.

**Solution:** Refer below code. You need to click on the dropdown down arrow element first so that dropdown values are visible. Then locate the parent element of these dropdown values (`//div[@role='listbox']`). Using this element, you can easily locate its child elements(which basically will be the dropdown values).

- `(//div[@role='listbox']//child::div)[3]` -- This is to select `ESS`
- `(//div[@role='listbox']//child::div)[2]` -- This is to select `Admin`

```
# Click on dropdown downarrow element
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "(//i[@class='oxd-icon bi-caret-down-fill oxd-select-text--arrow'])[1]").click()
# Click on ESS element
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "(//div[@role='listbox']//child::div)[3]").click()
```

**Check the complete working code and explanation below:**

```
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/web/index.php/admin/saveSystemUser")
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(30)

# below 3 lines will log into the application
driver.find_element(By.NAME, "username").send_keys("Admin")
driver.find_element(By.NAME, "password").send_keys("admin123")
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[@type='submit']").click()

# click on Admin menu
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Admin']").click()
# Click on Add user
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[contains(.,'Add')]").click()
# Click on dropdown downarrow element
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "(//i[@class='oxd-icon bi-caret-down-fill oxd-select-text--arrow'])[1]").click()
# Click on ESS element
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "(//div[@role='listbox']//child::div)[3]").click()
time.sleep(10)
```

**RESULT:**

[image]

### UPDATE:

 Click <kbd>F12</kbd> key, and click on the `User Role` dropdown. You will notice, `<div role="listbox">` element getting visible(see below screen).

[image]

Comment: I ran ur code and it worked out perfectly,I can understand everything except this one, 
  //div[@role='listbox']//child::div)[3], can u pls explain me this one? Thanks for your quick & prompt response.

Comment: Glad it worked! What part did you not understand?

Comment: So that's the XPath which will actually locate the value `ESS` from dropdown. There is a `<div>` node which is parent to the 3 dropdown values(which are '--Select--', Admin and ESS). You can inspect the page and click on dropdown, this `div` node will be visible. However inside this `div` exists the 3 child `div` elements which are the dropdown values. So what we are doing in this XPath expression is, locating the 3rd `div` child element of the parent `div` element. Let me know if you are not clear.

Comment: I understand ur explanation but from where did u fetch this '@role' attribute,  below is my HTML code,                                                                                                       <div class="oxd-select-text oxd-select-text--active" data-v-67d2aedf="" data-v-13cf171c="">                                                                                                            
<div class="oxd-select-text-input" tabindex="0" data-v-67d2aedf="">-- Select --</div>

Comment: Shawn,pls explain me @role attribute because I didnt see that in my HTML code

Comment: @Madhu - Check the updated answer. Let me know if you still cannot find it.

Comment: <div class="" data-v-957b4417=""><div class="oxd-select-wrapper" data-v-13cf171c=""><div class="oxd-select-text oxd-select-text--active" data-v-67d2aedf="" data-v-13cf171c=""><div class="oxd-select-text-input" tabindex="0" data-v-67d2aedf="">-- Select --</div><div class="oxd-select-text--after" data-v-67d2aedf=""><i class="oxd-icon bi-caret-down-fill oxd-select-text--arrow" data-v-bddebfba="" data-v-67d2aedf=""></i></div></div><!----></div></div>

Comment: Yes beneath this element(in your above comment), you should see `<div role="listbox">`. You will see it when you click on the dropdown.

Comment: <div class="oxd-select-text oxd-select-text--active" data-v-67d2aedf="" data-v-13cf171c=""><div class="oxd-select-text-input" tabindex="0" data-v-67d2aedf="">Admin</div><div class="oxd-select-text--after" data-v-67d2aedf=""><i class="oxd-icon bi-caret-down-fill oxd-select-text--arrow" data-v-bddebfba="" data-v-67d2aedf=""></i></div></div>when I click from the dropdown,the values gets changed like Admin/ESS based on our selection and I didnt find any code like yours with@role attr

Comment: ***"when I click from the dropdown,the values gets changed like Admin/ESS based on our selection"***  YOU SHOULD NOT SELECT THE OPTION FROM DROPDOWN. JUST EXPAND THE DROPDOWN SELECTIONS.

Comment: yep ,I found that, Thanks for your great help, you are an amazing mentor :)

Answer (score 1):

To locate the webelement for **User Role** within the website https://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/web/index.php/admin/saveSystemUser you can use the following [locator strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

- *XPATH*:

  ```
  //label[contains(., 'User Role')]//following::div[1]//div[@class='oxd-select-text-input']
  ```

Comment: I'm able to locate 'User Role' but I want to choose 'ESS" from the dropdown.

Comment: @Madhu _difficult in finding the locator for the webelement 'User Role'_ ???

Comment: Hi, i'm able to click on 'User Role' dropdown but I want to choose ESS from the dropdown for which im not able to find the locator, pls help me in that.

Comment: @Madhu Well somehow orangehrmlive is currently in _Spanish_ locale :) so unable to update my answer :(